# Xcode 4.5: The identity doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios6, code-signing

Just upgraded my Xcode to 4.5 from 4.3.2 and got an error: "The identity doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains".

Sounds odd, because i successfully built a code right just before. Sure, i have a private key, a valid certificate signed with a key, bundle name exactly match the provisioning profile etc. Nothing was changed except Xcode version.

The one new strange thing is that if i set profile selector to automatic mode it says "No profiles currently match) for Debug and Release, but do a right selection for Debug - Any iOS SDK and Release - Any iOS SDK.

May do i need to do something with an Xcode? Any ideas? Didn't hear before that iOS SDK affect on signing…

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I solve the Code Sign error: The identity ipad doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869486/how-can-i-solve-the-code-sign-error-the-identity-ipad-doesnt-match-any-valid)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527273/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-distribution-doesnt-match-any-valid-cert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841378/code-signing-identity-name-does-not-match-any-valid-non-expired-code-signing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949700/iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-non-expired-certificate-private-key-p

Comment: Please read carefully the WHOLE question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the new Xcode (i suspect that it was an Xcode) did a real mess with profiles.

I **deleted EVERYTHING (except private key, sure) at my Mac and any device**. And re-install: Apple WWDRCA, Development Certificate, all provisioning profiles.

Then manually set signing, because automatic selection pointed to wrong (non existed) profiles.

So i didn't need to revoke and issue certificate.

To any other commenators: Thanks, but i know how to sign apps and sure read all topics posted in comments. Please try to read carefully the whole question especially if you think it's duplicate. Mea culpa, i'm didn't specify that i already read similar topics.

Answer (score 2):

I lost so many days to close this issue too. I got this error after updating Xcode version. it was just because the Xcode was set by default to `device` instead of `simulator`. I hope it could help you.